# How can I make sure my overlay is above the Hero widget's overlay?

Tags: flutter

I'm using a Hero widget to animate a transition between two routes. The hero widget's child will occupy the entire screen in the second route.

I want to have a widget to be shown above the `Hero` overlay when the transition occurs: A button on the top left of the second route.

However, the `Hero` overlay placed above other overlays until the transition is finished. This causes the Hero to be above my own overlay during the transition (obscuring my overlay) until the transition is done.

How can I achieve the desired effect of having a `Hero` animation while at the same time placing the `Hero` overlay below my own overlay?

- There's no way to specify a z-index on `Hero`.
- There's no way to get the `OverlayEntry` related to the `Hero`, so I can't insert my overlay above the `Hero`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the widget that fills the entire screen be the first Hero widget and the button be the second widget. I solved this by:

1. In the first route, wrap the second widget in a Hero widget of its own.
2. In the first route, place the second Hero widget after the first Hero widget in the widget tree so that it is built after the other Hero widget.
3. In the second route, repeat the wrapping from step 1 and widget tree ordering from step 2.

Result: The second Hero widget will be drawn above the first Hero widget.

**Example**

- There are two widgets that will be in both pages: `PrimaryHero` and `SecondaryHero`.
- The `PrimaryHero` widget must be on top of the `SecondaryHero` widget during the transition animation.
- There are two pages to navigate between: `FirstPage` and `SecondPage`.

**Note:** The `PrimaryHero` and `SecondaryHero` implementations are at the bottom.

Implementation of `FirstPage`:

Note that the layout is a `Column` with the `PrimaryHero` widget at the top.

```
class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key});
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const page = Column(
      children: [
        PrimaryHero(), // <= Primary placed before secondary for layout reasons.
        SecondaryHero(), // <= Secondary placed after; this will cause an issue.
      ],
    );
    
    return const Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: page));
  }
}
```

Implementation of `SecondPage`:

Note that in this page, the `PrimaryHero` is placed after the

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const page = Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        /// Secondary placed first, so that it is behind Primary in this page.
        Positioned(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, child: SecondaryHero()),
        Positioned(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, child: PrimaryHero(isPushing: false)),
      ],
    );

    return const Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: page));
  }
}
```

Running the above code will show the flicker issue. As the second route appears, the `SecondaryHero` widget will be overlayed on top of the `PrimaryHero` widget during the transition animation, then when the transition is over, the `SecondaryHero` is finally placed behind the `PrimaryHero`. (flicker)

To fix this, we simply change the `build` method of the `FirstRoute` to this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  const page = Column(
    children: [
      SecondaryHero(),
      /// Insert Primary after Secondary hero, so that it is drawn after
      /// (therefore on top) of the Secondary hero.
      PrimaryHero(),
    ],
  );

  return const Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: page));
}
```

Well, that fixes the flicker issue, however now the layout is no longer what we initially wanted. In order to maintain the previous layout, it must be implemented with a different set of widgets (i.e. a Stack that draws Primary after Secondary, but positions Primary above Secondary.).